# Efficient way of finding min and max of a list by partitioning

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `List<Long>` elements. The list is huge. The list size would be around 1M records. I am trying to partition the list to get the min and max for each partition, which I will be passing them to the DB queries.
I am currently doing this in the following way:

```
int gridSize = 6;
List<Long> idList = findAllIds();
List<List<Long>> partitionedList = ListUtils.partition(idList, (idList.size() + gridSize - 1) / gridSize);
for(List<Long> ids : partitionedList) {
    LongSummaryStatistics idStats = ids.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingLong(e -> e));
    repo.callToDb(idStats.getMin(), idStats.getMax());
}
```

The above code works fine. But I am unnecessarily collecting all the keys to a list and then partition and save them (which saves them to a different list) and then looping through them to get the idStats.

Is there a more efficient way to do this instead of creating these many lists and consuming so much of memory?

Comment: Are you referring to this [ListUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html) (which is part of [Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) subproject of Apache Commons)?

Comment: If you are using ListUtils from Apache commons, then the inner lists are just *views*  over the underlying list and not copies of the elements.

Comment: Btw is `gridSize` supposed to denote the number of elements in a partition? Currently, the way you derive the `size` parameter (second argument to the `partition` method), the partition size is always 6 (`gridSize` value). Is this the intention?

Comment: I think you need to explain what you are trying to do, and what the DB operation is.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to prove that the problem is O(N).  Every one of the N elements in the initial list could be either the minimum or maximum.  So every one of them needs to be tested.

Therefore, for a single-threaded algorithm there is no performance benefit in partitioning the list ... compared to scanning the entire list in a single pass.  If you have the original list in memory, partitioning it and scanning the partitions does not improve anything.

If you are going to use multiple threads, then partitioning the list and scanning each partition with a different thread is potentially beneficial.  (You need to be able to create the partitions without copying the list.  That can be done efficiently using `sublist(...)` ... at least with an `ArrayList`.)

If you are going to use streams, you don't need to do the partitioning yourself.  A simpler way is to use `parallel()` and leave it to the stream infrastructure to do the partitioning ... which the spliterator can do *without* creating new lists for the partitions.

There isn't an explicit statement in the javadocs that the summarizing collectors will operate in parallel on a `parallel()` stream.  However the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LongSummaryStatistics.html) for `LongSummaryStatistics` says:

> *"This implementation is not thread safe. However, it is safe to use `Collectors.summarizingLong()` on a parallel stream, because the parallel implementation of Stream.collect() provides the necessary partitioning, isolation, and merging of results **for safe and efficient parallel execution**."*

In short:

```
List<Long> ids = findAllIds();
LongSummaryStatistics idStats = ids.stream()
        .parallel()
        .collect(Collectors.summarizingLong(e -> e));
repo.callToDb(idStats.getMin(), idStats.getMax());
```

(There is no need to use atomic types to do this because of the guarantees provided by the javadocs.)

---

On the other hand, if the real purpose of the partitioning is to partition the database queries, then your best bet would be to partition using `sublist(...)` and then submit tasks to an `ExecutorService` that will scan each partition and then do the DB query.

Answer (score 0):

I think that maximum performance that you are able to get is `O(n)`.

E.g. in case you have a `List<Long>` with 1M elements (whatever this is not a big data):

```java
@Getter
@RequiredArgConstructor
public final class LongSummaryStatistics {
    private final long min;
    private final long max;
}

public static LongSummaryStatistics calcMinMax(List<Long> ids) {
    long min = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    long max = Long.MIN_VALUE;

    for (long id : ids) {
        min = Math.min(min, id);
        max = Math.max(max, id);
    }

    return new Data(min, max);
}
```

Definitely you do not need to use stream to do this. This is pretty simple and native.

Then you are partitioning the list.

```java
List<List<Long>> pIds = List.of(List.of(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L),
                                List.of(6L,7L,8L,9L,10L));
```

The performance will not change - `O(n)`. Indeed, you do not need create a new list or modify it to calculate `min`, `max`.

```java
List<LongSummaryStatistics> data = pIds.stream()
                                       .map(ids -> calcMinMax(ids))
                                       .collect(Collector.toList());
```

And finally. In case you just partition the list by the section and not mix the original order, e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] -> [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9]]` for `gridSize = 6`, then you even do not need to make a partitions, because you can calculate the result on the fly;

```java
List<Long> ids = List.of(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L);
int gridSize = 6;
List<LongSummaryStatistics> data = calcMinMax(ids, gridSize); // [[1,6], [7,9]]



public static List<LongSummaryStatistics> calcMinMax(List<Long> ids,
                                                     int gridSize) {
    List<LongSummaryStatistics> data = new LinkedList<>();
    int i = 0;
    long min = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    long max = Long.MIN_VALUE;

    for (long id : ids) {
        min = Math.min(min, id);
        max = Math.max(max, id);

        i++;

        if (i % gridSize == 0 || i == ids.size()) {
            data.add(new LongSummaryStatistics(min, max));
            min = Long.MAX_VALUE;
            max = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

So you have `O(n)` time performance and `O(1)` memory performance. Which is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using java 8 only way could be as below.The essential part is you just need to use `SummaryStatistics` collector before actually realizing `ListCollector`.
For ways of partionioning you can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995763/java-8-partition-list)

```
        List<Long> idList = findAllIds();
        // List<List<Long>> partitionedList = ListUtils.partition(idList, (idList.size() + gridSize - 1) / gridSize);
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
            idList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / gridSize, Collectors.summarizingLong(e -> e)))
                .forEach((k,v)->repo.callToDb(v.getMin(), v.getMax()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache Commons Collections' [ListUtils#partition](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#partition-java.util.List-int-) method... the returned nested list elements are *views* of the original list (as it uses `List.subList`) and doesn't create copies of the list elements.

If you still want a simpler approach (without creating new (Sub)List instances), you can mimic what `ListUtils#partition` does and use an imperative approach to find the min and max as follows.

But before that, a word on your approach...

Usually we determine the number of elements in a partition (called the partition `size`) and then compute the number of partitions based on the size of the list. But in your code, the way you derive the value of `size` argument passed to the `ListUtils#partition` method, it looks like you have decided the number of partitions (= `gridSize` which is 3) and computing the number of elements in a partition. In the below answer, I'm sticking with the same approach as yours.

Here we have a helper function to find the min and max values within a range `(start, end]` of a list.

```
 //You can replace this with a class for JDK version < 16
record MinMax(Long min, Long max) {

}

private static MinMax findMinAndMaxForRange(List<Long> list, int start, int end) {
    if (list.isEmpty() || start < 0 || start > end || end > list.size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    Long min = list.get(start);
    Long max = list.get(start);
    for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++) {
        Long element = list.get(i);
        if (min > element) {
            min = element;
        }
        if (max < element) {
            max = element;
        }
    }
    return new MinMax(min, max);
}
```

Here, we have an IntStream range from `(0, numOfPartition]`, and find the *start* and *end* range values for each partition and call the above helper function. The minMax values for each partition is then updated in the DB.

```
int gridSize = 3;
int size = (idList.size() + gridSize - 1) / gridSize;
int numOfPartition = (int) Math.ceil(idList.size() / (double) size);


IntStream.range(0, numOfPartition)
        .mapToObj(index -> findMinAndMaxForRange(idList,
                index * size,
                Math.min((index * size) + size, idList.size())))
        .forEach(minMax -> repo.callToDb(minMax.min(), minMax.max()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. If you don't mind, can you explain how we can determine the partition size based on the number of elements in the list?

Comment: @Vamsi What is your requirement? Fix the number of partitions or number of elements in a partition?

Comment: it's to have a fixed number of partitions. but I got curious to know how we can have a dynamic number of partitions based on list size after reading your response.

Comment: If you fix the number of elements in a partition (say `size`), then the `numOfPartition` would be `(int) Math.ceil(idList.size() / (double) size);` i.e., `<size of list> / <partition size>` but the last partition could be smaller when not equally divisible.