# Java - Stream - Collect every N elements

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to learn java - stream. I am able to do simple iteration / filter / map / collection etc.

When I was kind of trying to collect every 3 elements and print as shown here in this example, [collect every 3 elements and print and so on...]

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j");

    int count=0;
    String append="";
    for(String l: list){
        if(count>2){
            System.out.println(append);
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            append="";
            count=0;
        }
        append = append + l;
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(append);
```

**output:**

```
abc
-------------------
def
-------------------
ghi
-------------------
j
```

I am not getting any clue how to do this using stream. Should i implement my own collector to achieve this?

Comment: Streams are the wrong approach to do that. When working with streams you are supposed to do *stateless operations* on each element so that they can be executed in parallel and/or in any order if needed. The counter for the elements however *is* a state.  You should better use regular `for` loop.

Comment: Also, you can use `Iterables.partition` from Guava.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28211518/2711488

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split list into multiple lists with fixed number of elements in java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210775/split-list-into-multiple-lists-with-fixed-number-of-elements-in-java-8)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can actually use an `IntStream` to simulate your list's pagination.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j");

int pageSize = 3;

IntStream.range(0, (list.size() + pageSize - 1) / pageSize)
        .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(i * pageSize, Math.min(pageSize * (i + 1), list.size())))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

which outputs:

```
[a, b, c]
[d, e, f]
[g, h, i]
[j]
```

If you want to generate Strings, you can use `String.join` since you are dealing with a `List<String>` directly:

```
.mapToObj(i -> String.join("", list.subList(i * pageSize, Math.min(pageSize * (i + 1), list.size()))))
```

Comment: Cool... i should have known about sublist

Comment: *FYI:* This is only a good answer if input is an array-based `List` (e.g. `ArrayList` or `Arrays.asList()`). For `LinkedList` and other `Collection` objects, where `get(int index)` is not _O(1)_, performance will suffer. --- Also not usable if input is a Stream, which is one interpretation of question: *How to collect every N elements from a Stream*. --- Still, +1 for useful answer.

Comment: @Andreas True, I'm just again linking here [the solution provided by Holger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210775/split-list-into-multiple-lists-with-fixed-number-of-elements-in-java-8/28211518#28211518) if the source is a stream

Answer (score 12):

You can create your own `Collector`. The easiest way is to call [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-).

Since your use case requires values to be processed in order, here is an implementation that simply doesn't support parallel processing.

```
public static Collector<String, List<List<String>>, List<List<String>>> blockCollector(int blockSize) {
    return Collector.of(
            ArrayList<List<String>>::new,
            (list, value) -> {
                List<String> block = (list.isEmpty() ? null : list.get(list.size() - 1));
                if (block == null || block.size() == blockSize)
                    list.add(block = new ArrayList<>(blockSize));
                block.add(value);
            },
            (r1, r2) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Parallel processing not supported"); }
    );
}
```

*Test*

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j");
List<List<String>> output = input.stream().collect(blockCollector(3));
output.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
[a, b, c]
[d, e, f]
[g, h, i]
[j]
```

Answer (score 11):

If you have Guava in your project, you can use `Iterables.partition` method:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import com.google.common.collect.Streams;
...

Stream<List<String>> stream = Streams.stream(Iterables.partition(list, 3));
```

Comment: I do not use it. I could. ll try

Comment: Good easy solution if potential extra jar is an option and input is an `Iterable` (most often the case), but not usable if input is a stream, which is one interpretation of question: *How to collect every N elements from a Stream*. Still, +1 for useful answer.

Answer (score 7):

I solved it like this:

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j");
    int groupBy = 3;

    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);         
    Map<Integer, List<String>> groups = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(cdm -> index.getAndIncrement()/groupBy));

    System.out.println(groups);
```

It prepares a map where the line number is the key and the strings on the line are in the key.

Comment: very interesting

Comment: clever, but it's side-effecting tho.

Answer (score 4):

I think the bets approach is using an amazing library [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) of [Tagir Valeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856258/tagir-valeev). The solution fits in one line ))

```
StreamEx.ofSubLists(list, 3).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution:

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size() / N)
         .map(i -> i * charactersAmount)
         .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(i, i + charactersAmount)
         .collect(Collectors.toWhateverYouWant());
```

The first line - you will get a stream of ints from 0 to amount of resulting lines. From your example, list.size() / N equals 4, so stream will be 0-1-2-3.

The second line - this stream will be mapped to the scaled by the charactersAmount one, in your case it is 3 - 0-3-6-9.

The third line will cut sublists out of your initial list.

The last line just treats the resulting stream as collection