# How do I sort a List of TreeSets with java8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, treeset

My list contains sets like `[1,3,5][2,6,4]` etc, all of the same size.
I tried doing this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
List<TreeSet<T>> block;
    for(TreeSet<T> t : block){
        block.stream().sorted((n,m)->n.compareTo(m)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    }
```

The end result I want is `[1,2,3][4,5,6]`.

I could try to add all the elements in an `ArrayList` and sort that out then make a new `List` of `TreeSet`'s. But is there is some kind of one liner?

**UPDATE:**

```
List<T> list=new ArrayList<T>();
    for(TreeSet<T> t : block){

        for(T t1 : t)
        {
            list.add(t1);   

        }
    }

    list=list.stream().sorted((n,m)->n.compareTo(m)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This works but could this be simplified?

Comment: Just to be sure - you want to rearange the elements so each set has three elements, and the sets themselves are  in ascending order?

Comment: sure there is a one liner, if you start far enough to the left, and set your margin far enough to the right.  And once written, nobody would ever be able to read it.

Comment: Yeah that is the end result i want @Mureinik

Comment: @MikeNakis An 50 inch monitor would be must in that case

Comment: @LexByte This isn't an exact duplicate, but https://stackoverflow.com/q/43057690/2422776 should steer you in the right direction

Comment: @LexByte can you use guava?

Comment: That code doesn't work because you're comparing sets with sets.  However, it's evident that the sets are basically irrelevant - it looks like you need to flatten, and then sort *that*.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yeah i was compering sets with sets.Is there any way to transform all those sets in an arraylist and collect it? I updated the post with a solution that kinda works.

Comment: @LexByte you need to `flatMap` and then sort and then collect. `block.stream().flatMap(Set::stream).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList())`. Notice that `(n,m)->n.compareTo(m)` is not needed at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Eugene's answer is sweet, because Guava is sweet. But if you happen to not have Guava in your classpath, here's another way:

```
List<Set<Integer>> list = block.stream()
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .sorted()
    .collect(partitioning(3));
```

First, I'm flatmapping all the sets into one stream, then I'm sorting all the elements and finally, I'm collecting the whole sorted stream to a list of sets. For this, I'm invoking a helper method that uses a custom collector:

```
private static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<Set<T>>> partitioning(int size) {
    class Acc {
        int count = 0;
        List<Set<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        void add(T elem) {
            int index = count++ / size;
            if (index == list.size()) list.add(new LinkedHashSet<>());
            list.get(index).add(elem);
        }

        Acc merge(Acc another) {
            another.list.stream().flatMap(Set::stream).forEach(this::add);
            return this;
        }
    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::add, Acc::merge, acc -> acc.list);
}
```

The method receives the size of each partition and uses the `Acc` local class as the mutable structure to be used by the collector. Inside the `Acc` class, I'm using a `List` that will contain `LinkedHashSet` instances, which will hold the elements of the stream.

The `Acc` class keeps the count of all the elements that have been already collected. In the `add` method, I calculate the index of the list and increment this count, and if there was no set in that position of the list, I append a new empty `LinkedHashSet` to it. Then, I add the element to the set.

As I'm calling `sorted()` on the stream to sort its elements before collecting, I need to use data structures that preserve insertion order. This is why I'm using `ArrayList` for the outer list and `LinkedHashSet` for the inner sets.

The `merge` method is to be used by parallel streams, to merge two previously accumulated `Acc` instances. I'm just adding all the elements of the received `Acc` instance to this `Acc` instance, by delegating to the `add` method.

Finally, I'm using [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) to create a collector based on the methods of the `Acc` class. The last argument is a finisher function, which just returns the `Acc` instance's list.

Comment: Both well thought out and well explained.

Comment: Love the *single-purpose class defined within method*. Minor nitpick: it does not compile because `count++/size` is a `long`. Either `count` should be an `int`, or if kept as `long`, then `index` should be computed with `Math.toIntExact(count++ / size)` (although I'm not sure it would be that useful to support such big lists that we need to *sort*).

Comment: Hi, @Hugues Thanks for pointing that out. `int count` should do it for this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick edit @Federico. I find it difficult to implement `Collector` for custom needs, and this is a really good and inspiring example.

Comment: @Eugene I guess he wants to keep the sorted order as iteration order

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I've added another answer, to show that the combiner could be greatly simplified...

Answer (score 3):

If you have `guava` on the classpath this is a breeze:

```
        block
            .stream()
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));

    Iterable<List<Integer>> result = Iterables.partition(sorted, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding another answer since this would be bigger than a comment. It's really what the accepted answer has done, but with a "smarter" combiner that does not have to stream all the time again.

```
 private static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<Set<T>>> partitioning(int size) {
    class Acc {
        int count = 0;

        List<List<T>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        void add(T elem) {
            int index = count++ / size;
            if (index == list.size()) {
                list.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }
            list.get(index).add(elem);
        }

        Acc merge(Acc right) {

            List<T> lastLeftList = list.get(list.size() - 1);
            List<T> firstRightList = right.list.get(0);
            int lastLeftSize = lastLeftList.size();
            int firstRightSize = firstRightList.size();

            // they have both the same size, simply addAll will work
            if (lastLeftSize + firstRightSize == 2 * size) {
                System.out.println("Perfect!");
                list.addAll(right.list);
                return this;
            }

            // last and first from each chunk are merged "perfectly"
            if (lastLeftSize + firstRightSize == size) {
                System.out.println("Almost perfect");
                int x = 0;
                while (x < firstRightSize) {
                    lastLeftList.add(firstRightList.remove(x));
                    --firstRightSize;
                }
                right.list.remove(0);
                list.addAll(right.list);
                return this;
            }

            right.list.stream().flatMap(List::stream).forEach(this::add);
            return this;
        }

        public List<Set<T>> finisher() {
            return list.stream().map(LinkedHashSet::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::add, Acc::merge, Acc::finisher);
}
```