# Read X lines at a time from a text file using Java Streams?

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

I have a "plain old text file" where lines end with a new line character. For arbitrary reasons I need to read and parse this text file 4 (X for generality) lines at a time.

I'd like to use Java streams for this task and I know I can turn the file into a stream like so:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt""))) {
    stream.forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But how can I use Java's Stream API to "bunch" the file into groups of 4 consecutive lines?

Comment: This is often called "chunking," though I'm not aware of an easy, standard way of doing it Java streams.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to partition and process your file content into `n`-size chunks using standard Java 8 Stream API. You can use [`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) to partition your file content into chunks - you can collect them as a `Collection<List<String>>` or you can apply some processing while collecting all lines (e.g. you can join them to a single String).

Take a look at following example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ReadFileWithStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Path to a file to read
        final Path path = Paths.get(ReadFileWithStream.class.getResource("/input.txt")‌​.toURI());
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
        // Size of a chunk
        final int size = 4;

        final Collection<List<String>> partitioned = Files.lines(path)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / size))
                .values();

        partitioned.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

My input file [contains some numbers (one number at a line)](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wololock/ccdfce7710b160e3bae253fed1b6332e/raw/fd3d9d856321a403a592b82c815c72c3ae3f6f9f/input.txt), and when I run following code I get something like:

```
[0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, -3, 2, 0]
[1, -3, -8, 0]
[2, -12, -11, -11]
[-8, -1, -8, 0]
[2, -1, 2, -1]
... and so on
```

[`Collectors.groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) allows me also to use different downstream collector. By default [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) is being used so my result is accumulated into a `List<String>` and I get `Collection<List<String>>` as a final result.

Let's say I want to read 4-size chunks and I want to sum all numbers in a chunk. In this case I will use [`Collectors.summingInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) as my downstream function and the returned result is `Collection<Integer>`:

```
final Collection<Integer> partitioned = Files.lines(path)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / size, Collectors.summingInt(Integer::valueOf)))
        .values();
```

Output:

```
2
-1
-10
-32
-17
2
-11
-49
... and so on
```

And last but not least. `Collectors.groupingBy()` returns a map where values are grouped by specific keys. That's why in the end we call [`Map.values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--) to get a collection of the values this contained in this map.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this will work indeed, but there are better ways https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216421/1059372 without side-effects...

Comment: `Paths.get(ReadFileWithStream.class.getClassLoader().getResource("input.txt").getPath())` should be `Paths.get(ReadFileWithStream.class.getResource("/input.txt").toURI())`…

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for `java.util.Scanner`. In Java 9, you can simply use

```
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(PATH)) {
    s.findAll("(.*\\R){1,4}")
     .map(mr -> Arrays.asList(mr.group().split("\\R")))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

For Java 8, you can use the back-port of `findAll` of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37482157/2711488). After adding an `import static` for that method, you can use it like

```
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(PATH)) {
    findAll(s, Pattern.compile("(.*\\R){1,4}"))
        .map(mr -> Arrays.asList(mr.group().split("\\R")))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Note that the result of the match operation is a single string containing up to four lines (less for the last line(s)). If that’s suitable for your follow-up operation, you can skip splitting that string into individual lines.

You may even use the `MatchResult`’s properties for a more sophisticated processing of the chunks, e.g.

```
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(PATH)) {
    findAll(s, Pattern.compile("(.*)\\R(?:(.*)\\R)?(?:(.*)\\R)?(?:(.*)\\R)?"))
        .flatMap(mr -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 4)
                           .mapToObj(ix -> mr.group(ix)==null? null: ix+": "+mr.group(ix)))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: this last snippet... well, it just went to our code base (slightly changed), but so nice!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a straightforward way using Guava's [`Iterators.partition`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#partition-java.util.Iterator-int-) method:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt""))) {

    Iterator<List<String>> iterator = Iterators.partition(stream.iterator(), 4);

    // iterator.next() returns each chunk as a List<String>

} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception properly
}
```

This is only suitable for sequential processing, but if you are reading a file from disk, I can hardly imagine any benefit from parallel processing...

---

EDIT: If you want, instead of working with the iterator, you could convert it again to a stream:

```
Stream<List<String>> targetStream = StreamSupport.stream(
      Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED),
      false);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with the streams, the only solution I see is to write your own custom collector. It's not intended for that purpose, but you can make use of it.

```
private static final class CustomCollector {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<String> acumulateList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void accept(String str) {
        acumulateList.add(str);
        if (acumulateList.size() == 4) { // acumulate 4 strings
            String collect = String.join("", acumulateList);
            // I just joined them in on string, you can do whatever you want
            list.add(collect);
            acumulateList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    public CustomCollector combine(CustomCollector other) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Parallel Stream not supported");
    }

    public List<String> finish() {
        if(!acumulateList.isEmpty()) {
            list.add(String.join("", acumulateList));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static Collector<String, ?, List<String>> collector() {
        return Collector.of(CustomCollector::new, CustomCollector::accept, CustomCollector::combine, CustomCollector::finish);
    }
}
```

And use it like so :

```
stream.collect(CustomCollector.collector());
```

Comment: a slightly better name would be `PartitioningByCollector` or something along the lines...  also seems like a `StringBuilder` (or plain concatenation since java-9 would fit some much better then `acumulateList`)

Comment: and the entire beauty of Streams is when you really can compute the parallel processing... for this case you can ;) see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44357446/1059372

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I admit I just re-read it to understand it again ))) and well, we both think something is smart(er), until this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48225443/1059372 :)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner and another confession - the idea is not mine. It's Tagir Valeev actually. In java-9 he added this `(left, right) -> {
                                       if (left.size() < right.size()) {
                                           right.addAll(left); return right;
                                       } else {
                                           left.addAll(right); return left;
                                       }
                                   }` does not look like much and neither very cleaver, but it is

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner he is not, still at IntelliJ; but was granted committer rights for the enormous work in Streams API and StreamEx. If only you would understand russian - he has amazing talks on Stream API...

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), you could use its [`buffer`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#buffer-int-) capability:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt"))

Observable.fromIterable(stream::iterator)
          .buffer(4)                      // Observable<List<String>>
          .map(x -> String.join(", ", x)) // Observable<String>
          .forEach(System.out::println);
```

`buffer` creates an `Observable` that collects elements in lists of a certain size. In the above example, I added another transformation via `map` to make the list more print-friendly, but you can transform the `Observable` as you see fit. For example, if you had a method `processChunk` that took as an argument a `List<String>` and returned a `String`, you could do:

```
Observable<String> fileObs =
    Observable.fromIterable(stream::iterator)
              .buffer(4)
              .map(x -> processChunk(x));
```