# Sorting and filtering list of hashmaps (objects) using Streams

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, hashmap

I have list of hashmaps:
`List <HashMap<String, Object>> objects`
It is list of following objects:

```
{
    "name": "mark",
    "age": 12,
    "present": false,
    "strength": 11
}
```

Now, I would like to in efficient way to sort this list by some attribute and filter.

After this, I would like to get some page from given list.

```
String sortBy = "name";
Integer ageFilter = 1;
Integer numPage;
Integer pageSize;


if (ageFilter != null){
    sortedAndFiltred = objects.sortBy(sortBy).filter(age > 100);
}
else {
    sortedAndFiltred = objects.sortBy(sortBy);
}


List <HashMap> page = sortedAndFiltred.getPage(numPage);
```

Can you show me how to do it with Java 8 ? 
I am searching for some elegant way.

Comment: Map -> Stream -> Filter -> String

Comment: Don't forget to cast the result of the function you provide for your comparator (i.e `comparing(m -> (String)m.get("name"))`). The same applies for the filter. After that, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210775/split-list-into-multiple-lists-with-fixed-number-of-elements-in-java-8 to see how you can partition your stream into chunks. Then you can use `Stream#skip()` to fetch the desired page.

Answer (score -1):

Filter a map by age

```
map.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.getAge() - o2.getAge());
```

or for example by name

```
Collections.sort(map, (o1, o2) -> o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));
```

Comment: This does not even functionally complete the expected output in the question.