# How to extract every n continuous elements in a list in scala?

Tags: scala

Just to say I have a list with 100 elements. I would like to extract lists with length = 5(i.e., there will be 20 extracted lists, which is element 0-4, 5-9, ... ). Is there any elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to [group by](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_4.html) how many elemes you want in each chunk

```
scala> (0 to 99).toList.grouped(5).toList
res5: List[List[Int]] = List(List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7, 8, 9), List(10, 11, 12, 13, 14), List(15, 16, 17, 18, 19), List(20, 21, 22, 23, 24), List(25, 26, 27, 28, 29), List(30, 31, 32, 33, 34), List(35, 36, 37, 38, 39), List(40, 41, 42, 43, 44), List(45, 46, 47, 48, 49), List(50, 51, 52, 53, 54), List(55, 56, 57, 58, 59), List(60, 61, 62, 63, 64), List(65, 66, 67, 68, 69), List(70, 71, 72, 73, 74), List(75, 76, 77, 78, 79), List(80, 81, 82, 83, 84), List(85, 86, 87, 88, 89), List(90, 91, 92, 93, 94), List(95, 96, 97, 98, 99))
```

see - [Split list into multiple lists with fixed number of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459174/split-list-into-multiple-lists-with-fixed-number-of-elements)