# How to subdivide a list into multiple lists while processing in Java stream?

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following API call

```
cloudwatchClient.deleteInsightRules(
    new DeleteInsightRulesRequest().withRuleNames(existingRuleNames));
```

which fails because

```
 [exec] Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.MissingRequiredParameterException: BATCH_REQUEST_TOO_LARGE: Batch size cannot exceed 20 items. (Service: AmazonCloudWatch; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MissingRequiredParameterException; Request ID: 0f820dc2-38b8-11e9-8465-3718764429f1)
```

Now I understand that I have to make multiple calls to deleteInsight rules for cloudwatch in chunks of 20.

So conceptually I am looking for

```
existingRuleNames
   .stream().
   .chunkIntoSizeOf(20)          // This is an imaginary method, i need to convert it into something concrete
   .foreach(chunk -> cloudwatchClient.deleteInsightRules(
        new DeleteInsightRulesRequest().withRuleNames(chunk));
```

Now I cant find anything in the java 8 streams api that allows me to divide and process my lists into chunks. Kind of like the scala grouped functionality [Split list into multiple lists with fixed number of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459174/split-list-into-multiple-lists-with-fixed-number-of-elements).

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks. I can of course use an imperative style and use sublists, but I prefer to avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 0):

In the forEach below you can do whatever you want to do with the chunk:

```
//my list of 30 strings that needs to be processed (existingRuleNames in your case):
List<String> list = IntStream.range(0, 30).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());

AtomicInteger prev = new AtomicInteger(0);
IntStream.range(1, (int) (20 * (Math.ceil(Math.abs(list.size() / 20.0)))))
        .filter(i -> i % 20 == 0 || i == list.size())
        .forEach(i -> {
            List<String> chunk = list.subList(prev.get(), i);
            System.out.println("Processing " + chunk);
            prev.set(i);
        });
```

**Output**:

```
Processing [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
Processing [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
```

---

So your code should look something like:

```
List<String> existingRuleNames = ...;

AtomicInteger prev = new AtomicInteger(0);
IntStream.range(1, (int) (20 * (Math.ceil(Math.abs(existingRuleNames.size() / 20.0)))))
        .filter(i -> i % 20 == 0 || i == existingRuleNames.size())
        .forEach(i -> {
            List<String> chunk = existingRuleNames.subList(prev.get(), i);
            cloudwatchClient.deleteInsightRules(
                    new DeleteInsightRulesRequest().withRuleNames(chunk));
            prev.set(i);
        });
```